# getting 404 error accessing CFM page

Tags: iis, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I am trying to access a coldfusion file on Server.

The file with `xyz.htm` extension works fine where as when I convert the same html into coldfusion file, like `xyz.cfm` , it throws following error:

```
404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

May I know what could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming CF8 on IIS6?

Could be that you've not correctly run the wsconfig.exe tool which will tie in CF to IIS etc.

Need to know which version of CF, which webserver/OS & versions to help further.

Basically, the webserver needs to know how to parse .cfm requests; without running the webserver connector tool, it won't know which files to use to actually deal with the .cfm files.

Comment: It's CF 8 on Microsoft Windows Server, I am using windows 7 too. Let me know if you need more help.But other coldfusion files are running fine on the webserver.

Comment: Again, a lot more information needed. You say that other .cfm files work on the same server - good, that implies that CF is at least working on that box.  

 - are they working in the same website definition? Or only a different website on the same server?
 - Are you using any URL rewriting? 
 - What (if any) frameworks are you using?
 - What happens if you rename the file to index.cfm
 - If you have three files in the same directory, .htm, .html and .cfm, which one loads by default?
 - Which version of Windows Server? Which version of IIS?